# Rendering Values in Html using Python Django

Tags: python, django

** HTML FILE **

```
    {% extends 'shop/layouts/main.html' %} {% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>Collections</h1>
      {% for item in items %}
      {{ item.name }}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

** VIEWS.PY FILE **

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import *


def collections(request):
    items = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, "shop/collections.html", {"Item": items})
```

I need an help that I couldn't load my {items} on html it simply shows nothing in the output

Comment: change `return render(request, "shop/collections.html", {"Item": items})` to `return render(request, "shop/collections.html", {"Items": items})`, and it should work, considering you have data present in your product model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context says `Item` but your templates tries to access `items` - make sure the names match and it should work.

Comment: catagory = Catagory.objects.filter(status=0)
    return render(request, "shop/collections.html", {"Catagory": catagory})

Comment: {{ catagory }}

i simply  call like this but this methoed also don't works

Comment: You are spelling the context key with a capital letter `"Catagory"` but lowercase in the template `{{ catagory }}` - this is why